# How to fit all numbers on my display label? - Basic Calculator

Tags: ios, swift, numbers, display

I'm a beginner in Swift and Xcode. As my very first project without tutorials I try to do basic Calculator app. My goal is to make it look like original calculator app on iOS 9. Everything works, but I don't know how to fit all numbers on the screen. In Apple app, if there are more numbers, they're getting smaller. How to do that?

[image: Here's how it looks]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For UITextField:**

You have to set the [`adjustFontSizeToFitWidth`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextField/adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth) property to `yes` and provide a suitable small value for the [`minimumFontSize`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextField/minimumFontSize).

Both together will cause the `UITextField` to reduce its font size to fit the string in its bounds.

```
let textfield = UITextField()
textfield.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
textfield.minimumFontSize = 5
// ... more
```

**For UILabel:**

You have to set the [`adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth) property to `yes` and provide a suitable small value for the [`minimumScaleFactor`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/minimumScaleFactor).

Both together will cause the `UILabel` to reduce its font size to fit the string in its bounds.

```
let label = UILabel()
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.05
// ... more
```